# Jquery Facebook Autocomplete disapear after postback of Update Panel

Tags: jquery, ajax, updatepanel, jquery-autocomplete

hey,
i'm using the Facebook style autoComplete inside a asp.net ajax update panel,
by problem is when im doing a postback  to the UpdatePanel the Jquery Disapear,
Any Idead?

thanks,

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("[id$='DDL_Guests']").fcbkcomplete({
    json_url: "../../Search.asmx/SearchAC",
    cache: false,
    filter_case: false,
    filter_hide: true,
    firstselected: true,
    onremove: RemoveItem,
    onselect: AddItem,
    filter_selected: true,
    maxitems: 10,
    newel: true
});
```

});

Comment: Please show the relevant code.  A simple repro case would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a partial postback occurs it update your markup and so the element with ID `DDL_Guests` will not be anymore binded to the jQuery code you are using the first time the page load.

So you need to rebind your jQuery code after a partial postback event has occurred.

To solve this problem you have to add an `endRequest` event handler in your code and call a function that will rebind again the widget to the `DDL_Guests` element as in the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQueryInit();
});

function load() { 
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(jQueryInit); 
} 

function jQueryInit() { 
    $("[id$='DDL_Guests']").fcbkcomplete({
        json_url: "../../Search.asmx/SearchAC",
        cache: false,
        filter_case: false,
        filter_hide: true,
        firstselected: true,
        onremove: RemoveItem,
        onselect: AddItem,
        filter_selected: true,
        maxitems: 10,
        newel: true
    });            
}
```

Then simply call the `load` function from your body markup

```
<body onload="load()">
```

using this trick your jQuery code inside the `jQueryInit()` function get binded the first time the page load through the `$(document).ready(function () {}` and get rebinded again after a partial page postback caused by the UpdatePanel

Hope it helps